# Why does print_r() display array text?

Tags: php, printing

How can I disable the Array text? Everything works fine, but the Array text of `var_dump` or at least `print_r` is not what I want.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(21564) "Content" }
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://competitive.euw.leagueoflegends.com/de/ladders/euw/current/ranked_team_3x3";

preg_match('#<table class="views-table cols-6"[^>]+>[\w\W]*?</table>#i', file_get_contents($url), $match);
print_r($match);

?>
```

Array ( [0] => ) <--- This is the ugly part on it which has to be deleted

Life example to show the problem: http://bruteforce.tv/index.php/ladder

Comment: Add the language, please, or nobody will know what you need. I assume this is PHP?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: What do you mean "disable the array text"? You want to disable the native functionality of PHP?

Comment: http://bruteforce.tv/index.php/ladder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) it outputs a valid PHP representation of your variable, if thats what you are after?

Edit: OP wanted to output the result of the preg_match rather than debug it, `echo $match[0]` was the answer...

Comment: Now its array ( 0 => '', ) instead of Array ( [0] => ), doesnt help :<

Comment: Your not just seeing `array(0 =>` the first item in that array is your table html markup

Comment: If what you want to do is output the table onto your webpage, then you need to do `echo $match[0]`

Comment: Do you know how to replace some content with <span class="brc">content</span>?

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific on what you call array text. If you're talking about the `String(5)` part then you can just use `print_r` instead of `var_dump` otherwise, there's no reason to use either of those functions.

If `print_r` and `var_dump` behaviors are the same on your system it must be a PHP plug-in that's modifying the outputs - probably `XDebug`

Comment: Im using a Joomla extension called Jumi

Comment: Maybe it helps when you see a life example: http://bruteforce.tv/index.php/ladder